# How to access (and modify) arbitrary items in a hierarchy of classes in python

Tags: python

I have a class built in a way as follows for building a tree structure.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)


n00 = Node('n00')
n00.add_child(Node('n000'))
n00.add_child(Node('n001'))

n0 = Node('n0')
n0.add_child(n00)
n0.add_child(Node('n01'))
n0.add_child(Node('n02'))

n1 = Node('n1')
n1.add_child(Node('n10'))
n1.add_child(Node('n11'))

n20 = Node('n20')
n20.add_child(Node('n200'))
n20.add_child(Node('n201'))

n2 = Node('n2')
n2.add_child(n20)
n2.add_child(Node('n21'))

h = Node('head')
h.add_child(n00)
h.add_child(n01)
h.add_child(n02)
```

Now that when I want to only access an item, it can be done by with a simple function such as:

```
def access(tree, *id):
    item = tree
    for i in id:
        item = item.children[i]

    return item.data

print(access(h,0,1))
```

The problem is when I want to make changes to any node, I cannot use this method and always need to manually type in the lengthy members such as:

```
h.children[1].children[0].data = 'new value'
```

or

```
h.children[0].children[0].children[1].add_child(Node('n0010'))
```

Now whenever the depth of the tree gets deeper, it becomes quite painful to repeatedly type all this.
Is there a 'Python' way to make changes to items in a tree similar to the access method?

Comment: A recursion should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and modify the node: Use the same "walking" technique as in your `access` method, only then don't return `item.data` but assign a new value to it:

```
def modify(new_data, tree, *id):
    item = tree
    for i in id:
        item = item.children[i]

    item.data = new_data
```

Example:

```
print(access(h, 0, 1))
modify("n001new", h, 0, 1)
print(access(h, 0, 1))
```

Which prints:

```
n001
n001new
```

---

Same thing for adding children:

```
def insert_child(new_child, tree, *id):
    item = tree
    for i in id:
        item = item.children[i]

    item.add_child(new_child)
```

Call it like:

```
insert_child(Node('n0010'), h, 0, 1)
```

Comment: How did I completely overlook this ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you know the "path" in the tree of the node you wish to edit, you could create a method to your `Node` class to return that node using recursion. Something like this:

```
def getnode(self, path):
    if len(path) > 1:
        return self.children[path[0]].getnode(path[1:])
    else:
        return self.children[path[0]]
```

Here path is a tuple or a list. For example `h.getnode((1, 0)).data` is equivalent to `h.children[1].children[0].data`

You can improve this simple method with some `try except` block to prevent errors in case a tuple is too long or with wrong index, if needed.

EDIT
using the * operator maybe is simple:

```
def getnode(self, *path):
    if len(path) > 1:
        return self.children[path[0]].getnode(*path[1:])
    else:
        return self.children[path[0]]
```

this way you just write `h.getnode(1, 0).data` (no double parentheses)

Comment: Had the class definition been modifiable, I would've preferred your solution. Unfortunately, the class def is 'hidden' and needed to find another way